# Why is Mi-35M so huge in size?

Tags: military, helicopter, russia

Why is Mi-35M so huge in size?

What is the benefit of having an attack helicopter to be so big?

If there is no benefit, why wasn't its size reduced?

Apache is not as huge as this.

Comment: My only answer is needs of the missions. No other explanation.

Comment: Also, once designed, even with changing needs, it's expensive to revise designs. Mil does now create the Mi-28, a much closer analogue to the Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Apache is pure attack helicopter with just two crew. Hind is a mixed role attack and light transport helicopter with additional room for 8 troops. Different role, different size.

Comment: Also, Hind was based on the Mi-8 transport in a much more literal take on the same thought process that created the HueyCobra from the Huey. It just retained the transport capability, although I understand it to be infrequently used.